# office component installation on Azure web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, oledb

Our web application using oledb for excel import and export, we have install  microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider on the local machine,  but we have published the website on azure web app , so how to install microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider on azure web app.

please help us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to install microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider on azure web app.

TL;DR: You Can Not.

Slightly longer: you do not have the access to the underlying machine or operating system necessary to install COM components. You need to either use a different (non-COM) component that can do the same thing or use a VM where you do control the OS. (Using containers for app services is in preview which might give you another approach, customising the OS as part of the publication of the container.)

Also, Office components are specifically *not supported* for use in non-interactive processes (eg. web apps), so even if you can use the component you may have odd issues (whether the OleDB provider falls into this classification is unclear).