# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine MS Azure. (Concrete answer)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, oledb

I need to fix this issue:
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I have seen many answers in StackOver but none of them is really helpful, basically, the problem is with MS Azure web app. I am looking for something that helps to fix this issue and/or a different solution which allows using Excel file in a web app.

How can I fix this issue?
Please, can somebody help me out with a concrete answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using an Access MDB database? If so, don't use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB`, use the older `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` driver and make sure you're compiling for 32-bit architecture and set your Azure App Service to 32-bit as well (the `Jet.OLEDB.4.0` driver is only available as a 32-bit driver)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [office component installation on Azure web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091737/office-component-installation-on-azure-web-app)

Comment: No, I am actually using an Excel file to map a table in the database.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I am not asking for the installation of the office components in Azure web app, I need to solve this issue and/or find a solution which works for me and for everybody,

Comment: I used the Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and it displayed this error: Server Error in '/' Application. External table is not in the expected format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who helped me.

I found the solution on my own.
The problem is that MS Azure does not allow Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 so, we can actually use an excel file but changing the configuration in the web.config to Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0, these are the two ways to use them:

```
<add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
<add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'"/>
```

The first one is for .xlsx extension (MS Excel 2007, NOT ALLOWED by MS Azure).
The second one is for .xls extension (MS Excel 2003, ALLOWED by MS Azure).

This is a solution without changing the code or modifying anything in the development process. In the code we can use something like this:

```
string conString = string.Empty;
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 97-03.
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
            }
```

This will allow us to work in DEV and PROD once we are done with our code. 
Finally, the web app in Azure should work properly, remembering we must use .xls extension (MS Excel 2003).

Answer (score 0):

> a different solution which allows using Excel file in a web app.

You could try [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) as an alternative to reading/writing files in your web app.

EPPlus is a .NET library that reads and writes Excel files using the Office Open XML format (xlsx). EPPlus has no dependencies other than .NET.

This library maybe more feature-rich than you need but it should satisfy your use case.